# Закрытие спойлера при открытии следющего

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.spoiler_links').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('normal');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s2-item-wrap spoiler-wrap disabled">
  <a href="#q" class="s2-item spoiler_links">
    <span class="img-wrap"><img src="img/icons/section_2/22.png" alt="Alt">
  </span>
    <span class="s2-item-text">Электротехника</span>
  </a>
  <div class="spoiler-body spoiler_body"><b>Ваш интерес здесь</b>
    <a href="#q" class="button">
      <span class="pulse-button">Вопрос эксперту</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сделал спойлер, использую данный `js` код. Помогите пожалуйста, сделать так, чтобы при открытии одного, другой автоматически закрывался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так, если ориентироваться на ваш HTML. И если вы хотите одинаковую анимацию скрытия всех блоков

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.spoiler_links').each(function() {

   $(this).click(function(e) {
      var nextElem =  $(this).next('.spoiler_body')
     
      e.preventDefault(); //отменяем стандартное действие ссылки
      $('.spoiler_body').not(nextElem).each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });

      if (nextElem.css('display') === 'block') {
        nextElem.hide();
        return;
      }
      
      nextElem.fadeIn(300);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.spoiler_body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoiler-wrap disabled">
    <a href="#q" class="s2-item spoiler_links">Электротехника</a>
      <div class="spoiler-body spoiler_body">Ваш интерес здесь
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler-wrap disabled">
    <a href="#q" class="s2-item spoiler_links">Электротехника 2</a>
      <div class="spoiler-body spoiler_body">Ваш интерес здесь
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler-wrap disabled">
    <a href="#q" class="s2-item spoiler_links">Электротехника 3</a>
      <div class="spoiler-body spoiler_body">Ваш интерес здесь
  </div>
</div>
```

Если анимация активного блока должна быть одинаковой для раскрытия и скрытия, то вот так

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('.spoiler_links').each(function() {

   $(this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //отменяем стандартное действие ссылки
      $('.spoiler_body').not($(this).next()).each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });

      $(this).next('.spoiler_body').fadeToggle(300);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.spoiler_body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoiler-wrap disabled">
    <a href="#q" class="s2-item spoiler_links">Электротехника</a>
      <div class="spoiler-body spoiler_body">Ваш интерес здесь
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler-wrap disabled">
    <a href="#q" class="s2-item spoiler_links">Электротехника 2</a>
      <div class="spoiler-body spoiler_body">Ваш интерес здесь
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler-wrap disabled">
    <a href="#q" class="s2-item spoiler_links">Электротехника 3</a>
      <div class="spoiler-body spoiler_body">Ваш интерес здесь
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все супер, спасибо большое, а можно еще маленький вопрос, анимация появления немного поменялась, раньше она выходила будто из центра а сейчас выдвигается сверху внизу, как можно заменить эффект появления ?

Comment: и если кликаешь по одному и тому же 2 раза, он открывается по новой, а можно сделать чтобы он закрывался при втором клике на один и тот же блок

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы он не просто выдвигался, а выдвигался со стилями появления из opacity:0 в opacity:1 и эффект закрытия при 2 клике

Comment: @АлексейСоколов Я поправил код, согласно вашим пожеланиям

Comment: @АлексейСоколов все. Окончательно поправил все и проверил. Два варианта на выбор вам. Тот, который нужен Вас, как я понял, это первый вариант

Comment: а можно как-то совместить slideToggle и fadeToggle ? чтобы и выдвигался и эффект появления был ?

Comment: все, нашел другое решение проблемы, а так все работает отлично, спасибо Вам огромное, а то уже 2 день возился с этим

Comment: Не поможешь пожалуйста еще немного, надо чтобы при открытии делался скролл к появляющемуся тексту, а то у меня сами эти блоки большие, и то что открывается в экране не помещается, они намного ниже, и надо чтобы при открытии был скролл к появляющемуся блоку, через id задал но не работает

Comment: Я осуществил как и хотел все, но когда нажимаешь на ссылку почти незаметно что внизу появляется дополнительный текст, помоги пожалуйста чтобы к нему скролилось, буду тебе оочень благодарен, у меня ничего хорошего не получается, как бы я не пробовал. Вот что получилось сейчас [РЕЗУЛЬТАТ](http://test.asvpages.ru/t66/service2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сохранить предыдущая спойлера которые открыли.

пример (angular):

```
onSpoilerClick(newSpoiler) {
    if (this.prevSpoiler && this.prevSpoiler.isOpen && this.prevSpoiler !== newSpoiler) {
      newSpoiler.isOpen = false;
    }
    newSpoiler.isOpen = !newSpoiler.isOpen;
    this.prevSpoiler = newSpoiler;

  }
```